# JWTSigner sign is not allowing Map[String, AnyRef]

Tags: scala, jwt

I am facing an issue when I am trying to implement "sign" method to generate JWT token using JWTSigner in scala. I am using com.oauth0.java-jwt-2.1.0.

```
"com.auth0" % "java-jwt" % "2.1.0"
```

Code:

```
class JWTUtil{
    def sign: String = {
        val signer = new JWTSigner("secret")
        val map = Map("iss" -> Some, "aud" -> Some)
        signer.sign(map) //"Cannot resolve the overloaded method sign"
    }
}
```

I am getting error in calling "sign". It says "Cannot resolve the overloaded method sign". It accepts Map<String, Object>. Not sure if it will be applicable in scala too. I am pretty new to Scala. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because `sign` method of `JWTSigner` class expecting Map from java util package and in here you are passing scala Map collection to the sign method. Also, you need to explicitly convert the Map to the `Map[String, Object]`.

Following code snippet might help to solve your problem:

```
import java.util
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters.MapHasAsJava

object JwtStackOverFlow extends App {

  def sign: String = {
    val signer = new JWTSigner("secret")
    val d: util.Map[String, Object] = Map("one" -> 1, "two" -> "234").asInstanceOf[Map[String, Object]].asJava
    signer.sign(d)
  }

  println(sign)

}
```